# Disabled filewatchers in Pycharm Community use disk near 100%?

Tags: files, python, ide

My PyCharm is the latest Community (free) edition, and I read that filewatchers are not included.  But I find that without me asking for filewatchers, some process relating to them often uses my disk near 100% for many minutes.  See pycharm terminal output.  How can I turn this off?

[image: Pycharm terminal]

Answer (score 0):

OK the issue was [too low inotify watches limit](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit), a system setting which I set to 512K, and rebooted.  Now the errors are gone. Apparently pycharm Community version still uses filewatchers at some level.